# Solving a probabilistic optimization problem similar to (constrained) least squares

Tags: probability, optimization, least-squares

A simple constrained least squares problem could be the following:

For a given matrix $A \in \mathbb{R^{m,n}}$ find the vector $v \in \mathbb{R^n}$ that
$$\text{minimizes:  }\quad \| Az \|_2^2 \\  \text{subject to:  }\quad  z \geq0 $$

But what happens, if we want to find a probability distribution $\mathcal{D}$ over vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ to:

$$\text{minimize:  }\quad \mathbb{E}_{v \sim D}[\| Az \|_2^2] \\  \text{subject to:  }\quad  \mathbb{E}[z] = 0 $$

I searched for both probabilistic least squares and probabilistic quadratic programming (because, if we would not have expectation in there, this would just be a special instance of a quadratic program) - but couldn't find substantial results.

Is there some standard approach?

Comment: $\text E_Z[f(z)]$ doesn't depend on $z$ any more so your objective function and constraint don't vary with the decision variable. Furthermore, if $\Sigma = \text{Var}[z]$, then $\text E[\|Az\|_2^2] = \text E[z^T AA^Tz] = \text{tr}(AA^T\Sigma)$ (using the mean constraint) and that's just a number. Would something like $\min \|Az\|^2_2$ be more like that you're talking about, since then it's random? You might find this helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_optimization. Or maybe you're varying the distribution of $z$? That'd lead to variational calculus probably

Comment: @jld , thank you for the link, this is helpful. Regarding the objective function, you are right; I have presented it inaccurately. In words: The objective is to find a distribution of random vectors $z$ s.t. the expectation over this distribution is minimal. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok yeah, I think that’s something that variational calculus can be used for since you’re optimizing over functions. In your case you have a functional $f \mapsto \int z^TAz f(z) \,\text dz$ as your objective and want to optimize it subject to $f \geq 0$, $\int f(z) \,\text dz = 1$, and $\int z f(z) \,\text dz = 0$. I’ll flesh this out into an answer tonight if someone doesn’t beat me to it.

Comment: My guess is that the distribution will be a point mass at the optimum solution to the first (constrained least squares) problem.  In fact, $z = 0$ with probability 1 would seem to work.